# Netbeans. how to make comment symbols appear next to code instead of on the left margin when toggling them?

Tags: netbeans, comments

Whenever I toggle comments in code, either via keyboard shortcuts, e.g. `ctrl+shift+c` or `ctrl+/`, or by the toolbar button, the single line comment symbol, e.g. `//` toggles in the left margin of the code, instead of just aside of the code, like this:

[image]

...Is there a way to make them appear next to the code itself like any other editor / IDE?

It is annoying specially when toggling already existing comments, because when removing them leaves the symbols with an extra space to the left, and re-adding the comment puts the `//` symbols in the left margin, AND leaves the extra space...

In general it makes a mess with version control when toggling existing 'normal' comments, specially when you toggle it expecting to remain commented as before, but now it gets "wrongly" commented, and shows as a change.

I couldn't find an option to set this, so I don't know if it's possible, or if there is a plugin to do it, etc.

BTW I'm using Netbeans 12.5 but this has happened since I remember, at least since NB v 8.0